# Python: Cannot find path (WinError 3) when running in CMD, but no issue when running in PyCharm

Tags: python, cmd, pycharm

When I run this Python code in PyCharm all works just fine. But when I run this code in CMD, I keep getting a [WinError 3] error message. I think there is something wrong with the path to my data file, but I'm not sure. Do you see the problem?

```
# Method call in "main.py" file:
FileIO.write("price_data.txt", self.data)

# Static method in "file_io.py" file:
@staticmethod
def write(file, data):
    """ Overwrites all data in "price_data.txt" with the data given """
    data_folder = Path("data/")
    file_path = data_folder / file
    with open(file_path, "w") as out_file:
        json.dump(data, out_file)
        out_file.close()
```

Comment: Can you please post the error? I'd suggest setting file_path to full path i.e "c:\data\price_data.txt". data_folder / file appears to be an operation rather than string concatenation.

Comment: This is happening because your filename doesn't include an absolute path. So the location is relative to the current working directory. When your run your program in PyCharm you are relying on PyCharm's notion of what the current working directory is (which in PyCharm is configurable). When you run the program from `python.exe` or IDLE the current working directory is almost certainly not the same. Check by printing the value of `os.getcwd()`.

Comment: This is the error: FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path: 'data\\price_data.txt'

Comment: If you don't know the value of `os.getcwd()` then you don't know where the interpreter thinks `data\\price_data.txt` is. To find out what the interpreter thinks it is, print the value of `os.path.abspath( 'data\\price_data.txt')`.

Comment: os.getcwd() prints: "C:\Users\wouts". The price_data file is at: "C:\Users\wouts\Documents\Eigen projecten\AutoTrade\src\data". Just for testing, I tried to hard code this path. But it still gives this error: " FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified: 'C:\\Users\\wouts\\Documents\\Eigen projecten\\AutoTrade\\src\\price_data.txt' "

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it! When I set the current directory in CMD to the project file, no error was displayed. You can set the current direcotry in CMD by the command "cd". Another solution is a little change in the python code:

```
file_path = Path(__file__).parent / "data/" / file
```

Path(**file**).parent returns the directory where you launch your application, I believe. From there you can easily search for the file you want.